# Area of an intersection of three ellipses

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let $\Delta := (A,B,C)$ be a triangle that is defined by three points in the Euclidean plane that are not collinear.
Let further $E_{(A,B),\,C},\,E_{(C,A),\,B},\,E_{(B,A),\,B}$ be the set of ellipses with two of the corners of $\Delta$ as their foci and the third on their boundary.

**Question:**
What is the area of the intersection of $E_{(A,B),\,C},\,E_{(C,A),\,B},\,E_{(B,A),\,B}$ expressed as a function of the triangle's sidelengths $a,\,b,\,c$?

Comment: You might look at [Finding ellipse-ellipse intersections in $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/a/347472/6094). Calculating the intersection of two ellipses is already a complex calculation, involving finding roots of quartics.

Comment: Suppose the points are at $(0,1)$, $(-2,0)$ and $(0,3)$. Then two of the ellipses have intersections at $$x= \frac{\mp 9 \sqrt{26} b+797702 \sqrt{130}-2638959 \sqrt{13}-6690567
   \sqrt{10}-29138642}{50442431}$$ $$y= -\frac{3 \left(\pm(-6 \sqrt{65}-12 \sqrt{26} +26
   \sqrt{5}+39 \sqrt{2})b+47051 \sqrt{130}-526905 \sqrt{13}-1464372
   \sqrt{10}-22007284\right)}{50442431}$$ where $b^2=4201243714808 + 55949265287 \sqrt{10} + 56446668509 \sqrt{13} + 
 362189770403 \sqrt{130}$, from which I conclude that any formula would be a mess.